# Why does JAXB not generate complete classes?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xsd

I have the following XSD:

```
<!DOCTYPE xs:schema [
        <!ELEMENT xs:schema (xs:element)*>
        <!ATTLIST xs:schema
                xmlns:xs CDATA #REQUIRED
                attributeFormDefault CDATA #REQUIRED
                elementFormDefault CDATA #REQUIRED>
        <!ELEMENT xs:element (xs:complexType)*>
        <!ATTLIST xs:element
                maxOccurs CDATA #IMPLIED
                minOccurs CDATA #IMPLIED
                name CDATA #REQUIRED
                type CDATA #IMPLIED>
        <!ELEMENT xs:complexType (xs:sequence)*>
        <!ATTLIST xs:complexType
                mixed CDATA #IMPLIED>
        <!ELEMENT xs:sequence (xs:element)*>
        ]>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified">
  <xs:element name="response">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element type="xs:string" name="status"/>
        <xs:element type="xs:byte" name="items_returned"/>
        <xs:element type="xs:int" name="items_available"/>
        <xs:element type="xs:byte" name="first_item_position"/>
        <xs:element name="result">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="project" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
                <xs:complexType mixed="true">
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element type="xs:short" name="id" minOccurs="0"/>
                    <xs:element type="xs:string" name="name" minOccurs="0"/>
                    <xs:element type="xs:string" name="url" minOccurs="0"/>
                    <xs:element type="xs:string" name="html_url" minOccurs="0"/>
                    <xs:element type="xs:dateTime" name="created_at" minOccurs="0"/>
                    <xs:element type="xs:dateTime" name="updated_at" minOccurs="0"/>
                    <xs:element type="xs:string" name="description" minOccurs="0"/>
                    <xs:element type="xs:anyURI" name="homepage_url" minOccurs="0"/>
                    <xs:element type="xs:string" name="download_url" minOccurs="0"/>
                    <xs:element type="xs:string" name="url_name" minOccurs="0"/>
                    <xs:element type="xs:string" name="medium_logo_url" minOccurs="0"/>
                    <xs:element type="xs:string" name="small_logo_url" minOccurs="0"/>
                    <xs:element type="xs:short" name="user_count" minOccurs="0"/>
                    <xs:element type="xs:float" name="average_rating" minOccurs="0"/>
                    <xs:element type="xs:short" name="rating_count" minOccurs="0"/>
                    <xs:element type="xs:byte" name="review_count" minOccurs="0"/>
                    <xs:element type="xs:int" name="analysis_id" minOccurs="0"/>
                    <xs:element name="tags" minOccurs="0">
                      <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                          <xs:element type="xs:string" name="tag" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0"/>
                        </xs:sequence>
                      </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                    <xs:element name="licenses" minOccurs="0">
                      <xs:complexType mixed="true">
                        <xs:sequence>
                          <xs:element name="license" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
                            <xs:complexType>
                              <xs:sequence>
                                <xs:element type="xs:string" name="name"/>
                                <xs:element type="xs:string" name="nice_name"/>
                              </xs:sequence>
                            </xs:complexType>
                          </xs:element>
                        </xs:sequence>
                      </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                    <xs:element name="links" minOccurs="0">
                      <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                          <xs:element name="link" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
                            <xs:complexType>
                              <xs:sequence>
                                <xs:element type="xs:string" name="title"/>
                                <xs:element type="xs:string" name="url"/>
                                <xs:element type="xs:string" name="category"/>
                              </xs:sequence>
                            </xs:complexType>
                          </xs:element>
                        </xs:sequence>
                      </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

But when I generate Java classes from it with JAXB, it does not generate *complete* classes, but only a content list after a certain point:
(`Response`, `Result` and `Project` gets generated properly. But the members of `Project` are not being generated)

```
@XmlMixed
protected List<Serializable> content;
```

and an according getter:

```
/**
 * Gets the value of the content property.
 * 
 * <p>
 * This accessor method returns a reference to the live list,
 * not a snapshot. Therefore any modification you make to the
 * returned list will be present inside the JAXB object.
 * This is why there is not a <CODE>set</CODE> method for the content property.
 * 
 * <p>
 * For example, to add a new item, do as follows:
 * <pre>
 *    getContent().add(newItem);
 * </pre>
 * 
 * 
 * <p>
 * Objects of the following type(s) are allowed in the list
 * {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link String }{@code >}
 * {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link String }{@code >}
 * {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link String }{@code >}
 * {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link String }{@code >}
 * {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link Short }{@code >}
 * {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link String }{@code >}
 * {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link String }{@code >}
 * {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link String }{@code >}
 * {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link XMLGregorianCalendar }{@code >}
 * {@link String }
 * {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link String }{@code >}
 * {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link Short }{@code >}
 * {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link Response.Result.Project.Links }{@code >}
 * {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link Short }{@code >}
 * {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link XMLGregorianCalendar }{@code >}
 * {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link Response.Result.Project.Tags }{@code >}
 * {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link Float }{@code >}
 * {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link Response.Result.Project.Licenses }{@code >}
 * {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link Byte }{@code >}
 * {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link Integer }{@code >}
 * {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link String }{@code >}
 * 
 * 
 */
public List<Serializable> getContent() {
    if (content == null) {
        content = new ArrayList<Serializable>();
    }
    return this.content;
}
```

I would like to have a variable for each element, e.g. like this one:

```
<xs:element type="xs:short" name="id" minOccurs="0"/>
```

Or is there a problem with my XSD?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because your complex type has `mixed="true"`.  The contents are in a `List` so that the mixed text content can be added between any two elements.

Comment: @rob - Remove the `mixed="true"`.

Comment: Thx! This is somehow misleading... i thought it is necessary because there are different types :)